# Do VB Macro viruses (ie macros in Microsoft office documents) affect modern Linux systems?

Tags: linux, virus, usb, office

In the area I live and work, viruses in outdated and pirated windows systems are absolutely rampant. (Moreso even than in the "normal" world). It's utter madness to plug in a USB drive anywhere. Almost 100% infection instant USB rate anywhere public.

Unforunately, I have to work with a lot of files with MS Office documents transferred by USB from students, which are generally equally as virus ridden. I know for a fact several of the Excel files I've gotten have contained VB macro viruses.

I have some concern about opening these even on a Linux machine, but it's unavoidable.

Is there any reason for concern that VB macro type viruses could infect a Linux machine using OpenOffice?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office macros and OpenOffice macros [are not compatible](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Macros/Can_I_use_my_Microsoft_Office_macros%3F), you would need to rewrite a Microsoft Office macro for it to run in OpenOffice.

Also, [macros in OpenOffice 3 are disabled by default](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Macros/Why_don't_my_macros_run_any_more_in_OOo_3%3F).

Comment: Note that this doesn't mean you *can't* write OOffice Macros or that everyone has Macros disabled in Open/LibreOffice. But: it should be relatively possible for virus scanners to remove harmful macros from office documents completely.